# Remove new line / line break characters only for specific lines

Tags: regex, sed, awk, newline

I have the following output:

```
02:01:31
OFFLINE
02:02:31
ONLINE
```

and I would like it to become:

```
02:01:31 OFFLINE
02:02:31 ONLINE
```

I found a way of removing all newline / line breaks with `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'` however  it gives me what follows which is not really what I'm after:

```
02:01:31 OFFLINE 02:02:31 ONLINE
```

**Q: How can I remove newline / line breaks only for lines that match a certain pattern (in this case `[0-9]` would be enough?**

PS: It doesn't have to be with `sed` as long as I can apply a regex pattern to the matching of lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your `s/\n/ /g` be `s/\([0-9]\S*\)\n/\1 /g` (a digit followed by any amount of non-whitespace followed by a newline).

Comment: The `*` belongs inside the group, not outside: `([0-9]\S*)`

Comment: Whoops. Thanks for the typo catch.

Comment: Working though I had to escape the parentheses to make the grouping work: `s/\([0-9]\S*\)\n/\1 /g`

Answer (score 2):

awk oneliner:

```
awk '/[0-9]$/{printf $0" ";next;}1'
```

test:

```
kent$  echo "02:01:31
OFFLINE
02:02:31
ONLINE"|awk '/[0-9]$/{printf $0" ";next;}1'
02:01:31 OFFLINE
02:02:31 ONLINE
```